# AngularJS $complite troubles in non angular Javascript

Tags: angularjs

I am using a non Angular mobile responsive framework and I am trying to integrate AngularJS data binding with it.

Any newly added content to the DOM (added outside of Angular) is not within the Angular's scope, and I am having trouble working out how to get it added to the scope.

This is what I have so far:

```
//non angularJS javascript here...
var app = framework({
   ....,
   preprocess: function (content, url) {
        //content variable is the content to be added to the DOM. eg "<div ng-bind...>......</div>"
        //need to use Angular here to add this new "content" to Angular's scope.
       return content; //need to return the content so that is gets added to DOM
   });
  ....
});
```

How would I add Angular into this preprocess function to compile the "content" before adding it to the DOM?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to reach the scope from js function and use $scope.apply() to make any changes to the $scope variable.

```
var scope = angular.element($("#yourController")).scope();

scope.$apply(function(){
    scope.hello = 'Hello World';
})
```

Comment: Thanks...What is "#yourController" in this instance as I am not using an Angular controller to add this content to the DOM? Is it the containing HTML element that the new "content" will be inserted into?

Comment: And also, at this stage (pre-processing) the content has yet to be added to the DOM. It is in the variable "content" `preprocess: function (content, url) { ` so we need to return it once it has been compiled by Angular so the framework can add it to the DOM.

Comment: It is your div element where you defined your ng-controller attribute,  where your scope is applied. I am not sure if there is a way to not use a controller when you use angular?

Comment: But a page can have lots of ng-controllers on it, so not sure which one to use. (sorry new to this AngularJS)